# imagepicker doesn't copy file to other location in flutter

Tags: file, flutter, imagepicker

I am new to Flutter. I just want to make a photo-taking and showing application both camera and gallery. But when I use below code, it won't save the gallery file in the app directory.

Actually, where is path provider stores file, and why it's not copying?
Is there any permission I'm missing.. please help me

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  File _storedImage;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Imagesave',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('image save'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            _storedImage != null
                ? Image.file(_storedImage)
                : Text('No image selected'),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text("hi"),
              onPressed: () {
                _takePicture();
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _takePicture() async {
    // 1. Create an ImagePicker instance.
    final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();

    
    final PickedFile pickedImage =
        await _picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

        if (pickedImage == null) {
      return;
    }

        File tmpFile = File(pickedImage.path);

        Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final String path = directory.path;
    final String fileName =
        basename(tmpFile.path); // Filename without extension
    final String fileExtension = extension(tmpFile.path); // e.g. '.jpg'

        File tmpFile2 = await tmpFile.copy('$path/$fileName$fileExtension');

        setState(() {
      _storedImage = tmpFile2;
    });
    //setState(() => _storedImage = tmpFile);
  }
}
```

Comment: have you added storage permission?

Comment: but in official page of imagepicker won't tell about that

Comment: yes, added but no file created. actually, I look in Android/data/package name/ folder

Comment: I am using android 10

Answer (score 0):

1.add latest version Dependency image_picker and path provider

2.give to below permission in Manifest file

uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"

uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"

uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"

3.And pub get

4.Run again